# Using $v_f = v_0 +at$ for objects in free fall

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, vectors, coordinate-systems

I have a question about the difference of using $v_f = v_0 +at$ and $s = v_0t + \frac{1}{2}at^2$ for objects in free fall. I'm trying to solve a problem where there's a ball rolling along an inclined plane and then it leaves the plane and after some time it falls on the ground.

I have a practice problem and by using the second formula I get the correct solution, but when I try to get the final $v_0$ velocity using the first formula I don't get the right answer.

Can I use the first formula for this problem?

[image]

$$v_f = v_0 +at \implies v_0 = 0 m/s - (-9,8 m/s^2)(0,8s) = 7,85 m/s$$ wrong!

$$s = v_0t+\frac{1}{2}at^2\implies v_o = \frac{s- \frac{1}{2}at^2}{t} = \frac{5 m - \frac{1}{2}(9,8 m/s^2)(0,8s)^2}{0,8s} = 2,33 m/s$$

correct!

Why are those results different if I'm using the same given final velocity (the object is at rest when it reaches the ground) and the same time?

Comment: You need to work with velocity components for this problem.  Break the velocity into its x and y components, and apply your formulas to each component separately.

Comment: @DavidWhite thanks. Isn't the horizontal velocity component always $0 m/s$ for the projectile motion?

Comment: I think I am actually finding the vertical component of the velocity. The problem is that I get two different results.

Comment: No.  You clearly have an object that is being displaced in both the horizontal and vertical directions as it rolls down the roof.  Once it leaves the roof, the horizontal component of velocity will remain constant, but it will NOT be zero.

Comment: @DavidWhite Thanks. This makes sense. What is it that I’m doing wrong to find the vertical component with the first formula? Because I’m using all the data that is associated with the vertical component. The acceleration is g?

Comment: Acceleration is g.  Acceleration while on the roof is g(sin(theta)).  Vertical component of velocity as the object is coming off the roof is v(sin(theta)).  You would do well to review free body diagrams and projectile motion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The two formulas both imply each other

To see why, imagine that you take a tiny increment of time $dt$ and calculate the tiny increment of distance $$ds=s(t + dt) - s(t)= v_0 ~(t + dt) + \frac12 ~a~ (t + dt)^2 - v_0 ~t - \frac12 ~a ~t^2.$$Computing the velocity after time $t$ is then the same as computing this ratio $ds/dt$ which is $v_0 + a~t + \frac12~a~dt.$ The claim is then that you can make $dt$ as small as you want to make this number as accurate of an estimate for $v(t)$ and so there is no harm in doing that. One can also go the other way, in which case one divides the time interval from $0$ to $t$ into some number $N$ of small periods of time $t/N$, where the total distance travelled is approximately $s = \sum_{k=1}^N v(k~t/N)~\cdot (t/N).$ Substituting $v(t) = v_0 + a~t$ gives two terms, $\sum_k v_0~t/N$ which is a sum of $N$ identical terms and is therefore $N~v_0~t/N = v_0~t$, plus a term proportional to a sum of counting numbers $\sum_{k=1}^N k,$  which works out to $N(N+1)/2,$ and that $1/2$ propagates out to give you this term $\frac12 a t^2$, plus a term which goes like $1/N$ and thus for a very good approximation it vanishes to 0.

## Where you are certainly going wrong

You assumed constant acceleration incorrectly.

Constant acceleration only holds when the thing is falling, but a new force emerges when the object impacts the ground (namely, the ground does not like objects passing through it and resists this mightily), so the acceleration rather sharply jumps when it is actually impacting the ground.

As a result when you say $v_f=0$ you are referring to the rest state of the object on the ground, but that takes you out of the nice world of constant accelerations that makes these equations work. Instead you want the final velocity just before the object starts making contact with the ground -- and that final velocity is not zero.

There are a couple of ways to get this. You have already witnessed one: the displacement formula does not have $v_f$ and so it can be rewritten so that you never need to determine it; you can use this to solve for $v_0$ and then use $v_f = v_0+a~t$ to calculate the final velocity.

The other clean way is to observe that in a situation of constant acceleration, the time-averaged acceleration $\bar a = (v_1 - v_0)/(t_1 - t_0)$ is of course just the constant acceleration $a$, while the time-averaged velocity $\bar v = (s_1 - s_0)/(t_1 - t_0)$ works out to being just $\bar v = (v_1 + v_0)/2$ as if one took a plain average. So one can calculate $\bar v$ directly and know what the sum of $v_1 + v_0$ is, and one knows from $a~(t_0 - t_0)$ what the difference $v_1 - v_0$ is, and then one can add these two numbers to find $2v_1$ or subtract them to find $2 v_0.$ Or if you prefer divide these numbers all by half from the beginning.

So in your case the average velocity must be $(v_1 + v_0)/2 = s/t = 5\text{ m}/0.8\text{ s} = 6.25\text{ m/s}$ while the difference you calculated, $7.84\text{ m/s},$ divides by two to be $\pm 3.92\text{ m/s}.$ So the two velocities are $v_f = 6.25\text{ m/s} + 3.92\text{ m/s} = 10.17\text{ m/s},$ and $v_0 = 6.25\text{ m/s} - 3.92\text{ m/s} = 2.33\text{ m/s}.$

Again, that 10.17 m/s figure is the speed immediately before the ground starts slowing the thing down.